# Serverless: Validation error ... Member must satisfy regular expression pattern: tablename

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cloudformation, serverless

I am trying to deploy a serverless app on AWS cloud formation but I am getting a regular  expression pattern error

```
Error:
CREATE_FAILED: UsersDynamoDBTable (AWS::DynamoDB::Table)
1 validation error detected:Value 'users-table-dev'' at 'tableName' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy regular expression pattern: [a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+** (Service: AmazonDynamoDBv2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationException; Request ID: 9OBFJ6RG2SKVIE58UTVAMNV7V7VV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG; Proxy: null)
```

What I can do to fix this?

```yaml
# serverless.yml

service: serverless-flask

plugins:
  - serverless-python-requirements
  - serverless-wsgi

custom:
  tableName: 'users-table-${self:provider.stage}'
  wsgi:
    app: app.app
    packRequirements: false
  pythonRequirements:
    dockerizePip: non-linux

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: python3.6
  stage: dev
  region: us-east-1
  iamRoleStatements:
    - Effect: Allow
      Action:
        - dynamodb:Query
        - dynamodb:Scan
        - dynamodb:GetItem
        - dynamodb:PutItem
        - dynamodb:UpdateItem
        - dynamodb:DeleteItem
      Resource:
        - { "Fn::GetAtt": ["UsersDynamoDBTable", "Arn" ] }
  environment:
    USERS_TABLE: ${self:custom.tableName}

functions:
  app:
    handler: wsgi.handler
    events:
      - http: ANY /
      - http: 'ANY {proxy+}'

resources:
  Resources:
    UsersDynamoDBTable:
      Type: 'AWS::DynamoDB::Table'
      Properties:
        AttributeDefinitions:
          -
            AttributeName: userId
            AttributeType: S
        KeySchema:
          -
            AttributeName: userId
            KeyType: HASH
        ProvisionedThroughput:
          ReadCapacityUnits: 1
          WriteCapacityUnits: 1
        TableName: ${self:custom.tableName}
```

I am trying to implement the code here [build a rest api with serverless lambda dynamo](https://www.serverless.com/blog/flask-python-rest-api-serverless-lambda-dynamodb/)

Comment: From the error message, it looks like you have an errant single quote (`'`) character being interpolated into your table name.  Check the value of `stage`.

Comment: @fedonev the value of  `stage`  is itself in the **serverless.yml** file under provider ->stage and it is dev only .  `stage:dev`

Comment: @fedonev I also changed  `users-table-${self:provider.stage}` to `users-table-dev` still same error any solution ? thanks for helping

Comment: Found the solution just delete the file and create a new file and copy the contents of original file.Just like IT crowd have u tried restarting it

Answer (score 0):

For anybody experiencing the same issue, take a look at the `tableName` property. Instead of having the single quotes the line should look like that

```
  tableName: `users-table-${self:provider.stage}`
```

Had the same minor error, it is easy to be overlooked.